# how to make android studio debug both flutter code and kotlin code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using flutter on android studio and it is working great.

Still, sometimes I need to use a native `kotlin` code in the project so I edit `MainActivity.kt` ,but the IDE stops debugging inside the kotlin code .

Even though I have the kotlin plug-in installed , So how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [corresponding flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/oem-debuggers#debugging-with-android-gradle-android).
This part explain how to debug both Dart code and Android code.